# Using a Windows DLL in Go with cgo

Tags: windows, go, dll, hunspell

I'm trying to use the hunspell library in a Go project on Windows.

I have [the compiled Windows DLL (x64)](https://github.com/mlt/hunspell/releases/download/appveyor_v1.7.0/hunspell-msvc-Release-x64.zip) and the corresponding [header file](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/tree/master/src/hunspell) (which is written in C), but I can't link it to the Go program.

What I've tried so far:

```
package main

//#cgo CFLAGS: -Id:/Go/HunSpellTest/build/
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -Ld:/Go/HunSpellTest/build/llibhunspell-1.7-0.dll  -llibhunspell-1.7-0

// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <hunspell.h>
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    C.Hunspell_create()
}
```

But with any combination of the paths and filenames (with extension, without extension, without version number, with relative and absolute path, using slashes or backslashes) I got the same error:

`undefined reference to __imp_Hunspell_create`

I've tried to add that path to the global `PATH` variable or put the DLLs into a system wide folder, but nothing worked.

Please note that I can link the DLL with the `syscall` package and call the `Hunspell_create` method, but I would like to use the lib like in the [hunspellgo](https://github.com/akhenakh/hunspellgo) package.

Comment: would you be ok with this? https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#NewLazyDLL

Comment: @StevenPenny: No, I can include the DLL via the syscall package, but I would like to use it with cgo.

Comment: fair enough - but be advised the `syscall` package is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`C.Hunspell_create()`](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/search?q=Hunspell_create) missing `const char* affpath` and `const char* dpath` parameters.

Maybe you also missing some `mingw-w64/msys2/cygwin` deps packages on Windows. [hunspellgo](https://github.com/akhenakh/hunspellgo/blob/master/hunspellgo.go#L9-L13) seem not tested on Windows. You needs a linux-like building system (such as `mingw-w64/msys2/cygwin`) to compile hunspell on Windows. See at https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell#compiling-on-windows . Golang with cgo support on Windows also need some `gcc/g++` deps.

Comment: I know it missing its parameters, but is not the problem. The problem is the compiler can't find the method itself. I have mingw-w64 installed, but I don't want to compile the hunspell package itself on Windows, I would like to use the precompiled DLL.

Comment: You need to `dlltool -dllname hunspell.dll --def hunspell.def --output-lib libhunspell.a`. In gcc/g++ does not using hunspell.dll or hunspell.lib as lib file.

Comment: @Fenistil You can `syscall` a dll file on Windows. But with CGO it needs `lib{name}.a` file. You must  generate it first. `undefined reference to __imp_Hunspell_create` means you missing `libhunspell.a` file. see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html .

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and respond

Comment: @Fenistil maybe you can using this directly: https://github.com/mlt/hunspell/releases/download/tst/hunspell-mingw64.zip